# Always Change value of a variable at a certain line of code

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I know that a variable value can be changed in the debug mode of Eclipse. But can I make that change happen every time a certain line is getting executed?
What I want to do is to make the change every time without manually having to do it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't you just add a line of code that changes the value?

Comment: @TrystanSpangler Yes, that is possible. I thought the IDE had some way of doing this. Otherwise I would have to rebuild when I want to execute with/without the change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I got you right, I might have a solution that suits your needs here (or at least "might have suited", for I must admit this thread is pretty old by now ... ;-):

I had a similar issue this morning, detouring a "mailTo" (just a variable holding the recipients adress). I came to use a conditional breakpoint with the following condition:

```
"42" != (mailTo = "a@bc.de")
```

You always hit the breakpoint because "42" (or whatever value ;-) will never be equal to the assignment on the right - which yet does the main-job here.

Its also possible to make it "really conditional" (if needed) by using `{real condition} && {fake condition}` (because the fake is then depending on a preceding 'true')

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that the breakpoint dosen't even need to be hit in order for the modification to happen.

Comment: That's right! We simply need the comparison here - very useful addition, thx :-)